# How to assign variable from different tables?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a list of tables of Make and Models of Assets. I need to assign the Asset Make using AssetMakeString. Currently I have:

```
    public class FuelLightTruckDataSource
    {
        public Model.Asset Asset { get; set; }
        public Employee Employee { get; set; }
        public FuelProductClass ProductClass { get; set; }
        public FuelVendor Vendor { get; set; }
        public FuelFillSource FillSource { get; set; }
        public AssetModel Model { get; set; }
        public AssetMake Make { get; set; }
        public string Source { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public decimal Volume { get; set; }
        public decimal? Distance { get; set; }
        public decimal? Odomoter { get; set; }
        public decimal? DistanceVolume { get; set; }
        public float? ConsumptionRate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
        public decimal? ConsumptionCalculated { get; set; }
        public decimal? DistanceCalculated { get; set; }

    public FuelLightTruckDataSource() { }

    public static List<FuelLightTruckDataSource> Get(DateTime from, DateTime to)
    {
        List<FuelLightTruckDataSource> data = new List<FuelLightTruckDataSource>();

        using (SystemContext ctx = new SystemContext())
        {

            List<FuelLightTruckDataSource> dataTransactions
                = ctx.FuelTransaction
                    .Where(tx => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(tx.DateTime) >= from.Date && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(tx.DateTime) <= to.Date
                        //&& tx.AssetFilled.AssignedToEmployee.Manager
                        && tx.AssetFilled.AssignedToEmployee != null
                        //&
                        && tx.AssetFilled.AssetType.Code == "L"
                        && (tx.FuelProductType.FuelProductClass.Code == "GAS" || tx.FuelProductType.FuelProductClass.Code == "DSL"))
                    .GroupBy(tx => new { tx.AssetFilled, tx.DateTime, tx.FuelProductType.FuelProductClass, tx.FuelCard.FuelVendor, tx.City, tx.Volume, tx.Odometer}) //Added tx.volume to have individual transactions
                    .Select(g => new FuelLightTruckDataSource()
                    {
                        Asset = g.FirstOrDefault().AssetFilled,
                        Model = g.FirstOrDefault().AssetFilled.AssetModel,
                        Make = g.FirstOrDefault().AssetFilled.AssetModel.AssetMakeString,
                        Employee = g.FirstOrDefault().AssetFilled.AssignedToEmployee,
                        ProductClass = g.FirstOrDefault().FuelProductType.FuelProductClass,
                        Vendor = g.FirstOrDefault().FuelCard.FuelVendor,
                        FillSource = FuelFillSource.Transaction,
                        Source = "Fuel Station",
                        City = g.FirstOrDefault().City.ToUpper(),
                        Volume = g.FirstOrDefault().Volume,
                        Distance = g.FirstOrDefault().Odometer,
                        Date = g.FirstOrDefault().DateTime


                    })
                   // .OrderBy(tx => tx.Date)
                    .ToList();
```

My AssetModel class looks like this:

```
{
    public class AssetModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        [Index("IX_AssetModel", 2, IsUnique = true)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(10)]
        [Index("IX_AssetModel", 3, IsUnique = true)]
        public string Year { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Index("IX_AssetModel", 1, IsUnique = true)]
        public int? AssetMakeId { get; set; }

        public virtual AssetMake AssetMake { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Asset> Assets { get; set; }

    // **** Custom Properties ****

    public string AssetMakeName { get { return AssetMake.Name; } }
    public string AssetMakeString { get { return AssetMake.Name + " " + Name + (Year == null ? "" : " (" + Year + ")"); } }
}
```

}

Why am I getting "Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'PSI.ManagementSystem.Model.AssetMake'"?

Comment: Did the compiler say what line the error is on?

Comment: @RFS, You just have to replace `Make = g.FirstOrDefault().AssetFilled.AssetModel.AssetMakeString,` to `Make = g.FirstOrDefault().AssetFilled.AssetModel.AssetMake,`

Answer (score 0):

`FuelLightTruckDataSource.Make` is declared like this:

```
public AssetMake Make { get; set; }
```

The type of `Make` is `AssetMake`. You can't assign a string to it. You have to assign an `AssetMake` to it.

Instead, you assign a string to it right here, and the compiler won't accept that, because it has no way to implicitly convert a string to an `AssetMake`:

```
Make = g.FirstOrDefault().AssetFilled.AssetModel.AssetMakeString
```

`AssetMakeString` is a string. It's declared like this:

```
public string AssetMakeString { get { 
    return AssetMake.Name + " " + Name 
           + (Year == null ? "" : " (" + Year + ")"); } }
```

So you can't use that string to initialize `FuelLightTruckDataSource.Make`. Instead of take the asset make you're getting from the DB, converting it into a string, and then assigning that to something you can't assign it to, what you want to do is just assign the asset make itself.

Do you think you can find a property of `AssetModel` which is of type `AssetMake`? If you read the class definition for `AssetModel`, you may find one. If you can find one, that might be the property you want to use instead of `AssetMakeString`.